# How to extract rows of a matrix based on conditions that apply to different columns at once?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

For example, say I have a 3-column matrix of news notifications, where the first column gives the serial number of news read in a sequence, the second column givess the Category of the news, and the third column gives whether the notification was opened or not (binary, 1 for read or 0 for not read). So, an excerpt might look like this:

```
1    12     1
2    13     0
3    13     1
4    12     0
5    14     1
6    13     0
7    12     0
8    13     1
9    14     0
10   12     1
```

And I want all the rows where notifications from category 12 were read. So, the output should be this:

```
1    12     1
10   12     1
```

So, if the data matrix is called `input`, and the resultant matrix I want is named `output`, I would write the following code:

```
for i=1:size(input,1)
    temp = input(input(:,2)==12,:);
    output = temp(temp(:,3)==1,:);
end
```

But I suppose this should a trivial thing to do in MATLAB. So, is there a one liner that does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
output=input(find(input(:,2)==12 & input(:,3)==1),:)
```

Comment: Note: the `find` isn't needed; direct logical indexing should suffice.

Comment: @TroyHaskin Yes, indeed

Comment: Wow, I feel so stupid right now. I should have been able to figure that out. And yeah, the `find` isn't required.

Comment: you shouldn't use `input` as a variable name, it's a function name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the supposed to be fast in-built function [**`ismember`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html), which is actually the dedicated function for what you want to achieve:

```
%// data
A =[1    12     1
    2    13     0
    3    13     1
    4    12     0
    5    14     1
    6    13     0
    7    12     0
    8    13     1
    9    14     0
    10   12     1]

%// sequence to search for
x = [ 12 1 ]

%// filtering
out = A( ismember(A(:,2:3),x,'rows'), : )
```

---

```
out =

     1    12     1
    10    12     1
```